# Why is Gmail taking so long to fetch new e-mails?

Tags: gmail

*Mobile Gmail in my Moto Z2 / Android 7 needs **ten times longer time** to fetch / show new e-mails in my mailbox than it happens in web version on my PC.*

Is there anything I can do about this?

---

For years using mobile Gmail (now with Motorola Moto Z2 Play / Android 7.x) it was clear to me that mobile Gmail needs much, much more time to fetch e-mails that its PC / web counterpart.

But now this went far beyond the level that I can accept. My Gmail needs literally 15-30 minutes or sometimes even more since e-mails is sent till it appears in my Inbox. While PC counterpart needs 2-3 minutes in the very same scenario.

Just an hour ago I wanted to sign-up to some service and I wasn't able to do this, because my mobile Gmail was fetching account verification e-mails after 30+ minutes since sending them. Which was too long, because service -- that I was trying to sign-up for -- allows only 30 minutes long account verification tokens and each time was showing an error that the token that I am trying to verify account with has already expired.

After three such unsuccessful attempts I opened up my laptop, used web Gmail and managed to complete the process within 3 minutes, because that was the time needed by Gmail to show up verification e-mail.

*fast.com* shows 30 Mbps for mobile phone and 60 Mbps for laptop, so network speed shouldn't be a problem here.

On contrary to other mail clients, Gmail doesn't have any frequency setting for checking e-mail and mails are checked with as often as Google thinks they should.

So, is there anything I can do about this?
Any thing to speed up my mobile version of Gmail?

Comment: I don't know what can be done but I've switched to this open source, privacy oriented [E mail client](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2605/131553) that is fast and much more flexible. I've been using it for an year without any problems and happy that I switched

Comment: AFAIK GMail app uses Google push notification to be notified of new messages in a GMail account. Hence there is no frequency setting. For comparing PC and smartphone make sure to use the exact same network because even if the tested network speed shows no issues this might be different to the GMail servers. Have you tried to clear the app data and caches of Gmail app?

Comment: Check any battery optimization settings for the Gmail app. The app won't sync if the device is on battery saver. Also, check the network connection between the Google server and the mobile, or otherwise try other email clients to confirm whether the issue is on the Gmail app or not. I got notifications from Gmail on both Android and a Windows 10 laptop almost at the same time when an email arrives.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments. I will try to address them all here though I am pretty sure that this is like looking for a needle in a haystack. So: I am using exactly the same (home) network with only difference that laptop is connected through cable so fast.com shows much, much higher network speeds than on wireless in mobile. I have just cleared cache and app data cleared and turned off battery optimisation and will observe for some time. If there is no difference, I'll switch to an alternative solution as suggested, thanks.

Comment: BTW: I have just noticed that in current form this question is not answerable as is too wide, too opinion based and in fact is a mentioned searching for a needle in a haystack. If we consider answering it, we should rather focus on answering, if there are any possible time-affecting problems, in scope and by design? Seems, not. I'd suggest anyone of you adding an answer focusing around of Andrew T.'s claim that there _should_ be no difference and only suggesting all these solutions you formulated here (battery optimisation, cache etc.). But, that is just a suggestion which I am leaving to you.